# Failed to resolve: com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2

Tags: android, github

I'm building an android system with help of a youtube video and when I try to sync it to fire base, it shows the following error.

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app

Here is my code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mynewrealtimelocationtracker"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'

    //RxJava2
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

    //Retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
}
```

I'm happy if somebody can explain me the purpose of having the below code.

```
implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'
```

Since I'm new to android I have no idea about above line.

Comment: It is a material searchbar library that the youtuber has used to implement the search bar. Your error is that the library path doesnt exist. Try to google search for that library. If that still exists now or is the version changed.

Comment: Have you added jitpack to the repositories section of your `build.gradle`? As per the README you have to do that to be able to fetch the artifact... https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a library for a search bar with material design style

https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar

If you haven't use it in xml then you can just remove it. I recommend you to do so, because if after removing it you keep having compiling errors then you have another error that is masked by that. Only after removing it and compiling you can know that was the problem and you can start fixing it.

Most likely the problem should be covered here

https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/issues/51

The libraries that are needed for the Android API indicate it on the name, usually as `androidx`. I'm guessing the root problem could be related with the copious amount of libraries that your are using.

If you are new to Firebase go to the docs and read the basic example for RTD this codelab should be enough

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

The rest of the libraries are just adding extra logic that could be a great architecture but you don't need to use Rx to use Firebase. There are other questionable stuff there as well, by example using paper db as a second database, what for if the project is already using Firebase real time database? This is a common problem with tutorials, my recommendation is follow the docs and then jump in more complexity gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Check the release notes at https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/releases and suggest you use the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

add in settings.gradle: maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositorios {
google()
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your settings.gradle file in the dependencyResolutionManagement maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

```
`dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}`